# Building lld on Apple Silicon

Tags: cmake, llvm, macos-big-sur, apple-silicon, lld

I am try to build lld from LLVM version 11 (I can't use any later or master version of LLVM for the time-being) and am currently configuring with `cmake ~/Downloads/lld-11.0.0.src/ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/bin/llvm -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$HOME/bin/llvm -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G Ninja` but `ninja install` then fails with 20 errors that I *think* are all standard library related (such as "unknown type name 'constexpr'" and "no template named 'underlying_type_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'underlying_type'?").

The compiler cmake is using by default is Apple Clang 12 which came with my system (or was installed automatically). What other flags should I pass to cmake to get this working? Or do I need to use a different compiler? LLVM 11 configures and builds fine with the same cmake flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else experiencing similar issues: Building LLVM, lld and clang from the [monorepo](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project) all in one go worked. I had to add `-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;lld"` to the cmake command.